# SSRS 2008 - Printing PDF in Portrait not landscape

Tags: pdf, ssrs-2008

Having an issue printing my SSRS reports, when I select PDF format, then click export, the report gets cuts off the right-hand side of the report. The PDF add an additional page for the left column that gets cut-off. The report displays fine in report manager and also in other formats such as Excel. My preference is to have report output in PDF. Also need help with page breaks in PDF's.

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

Check the **Page Setup** of your **Report Properties**.

You may need to change the orientation to **Landscape** to make it 11 inches wide by 8.5 high.

When you export to the screen or an Excel file, the width doesn't matter but when you print or export to PDF, it does.

The report Body width (10.5 in my case) + the margins (2 x .125 in) must be equal to or less than the Paper Size width - otherwise it will create a new page to fit the rest of the right-hand side of your page.

[image]

For your paging, check the **Grouping** window and click on the desired row (under Row Groups) to repeat. Then in the Properties window, set Page Break to where you need them.

[image]